# KeyboardAvoidingView AdjustResize not work in Android

Tags: react-native

I want the Next button not to cover the keyboard when I see it.
When I used `KeyboardAvoidingView`, IOS worked normally.
But it works like `AdjustPan` on Android.
The `manifest` is set to `AdjustResize`.

How do I make it work on Android?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button, Text, Container, Content, Header, Left, Body, Right, Icon, Input, Form,
} from 'native-base';
import {
  StyleSheet, Dimensions, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform,
} from 'react-native';


const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const titleTopMargin = height / 7.38;
const inputTopMargin = height / 12.3;
const nextButtonTopMargin = height / 6.246;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0,

  },
  headerViewsLeft: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    marginLeft: 23,
  },
  backButtonText: {

    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#666666',
  },
  titleText: {
    marginLeft: 60,

    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#333333',
    marginTop: titleTopMargin,
  },
  inputStyle: {
    marginTop: inputTopMargin,
    marginLeft: 59,
    marginRight: 59,

    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#666666',
  },
  nextButton: {
    marginTop: nextButtonTopMargin,
  },
});

class LoginEmailContainer extends Component {
  back = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
  }


  render() {
    const { back } = this;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={styles.headerStyle}>
          <Left style={styles.headerViewsLeft}>
            <Button iconLeft onPress={() => back()} transparent>
              <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>back</Text>
            </Button>
          </Left>
        </Header>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior="padding"
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <Content scrollEnabled bounces={false} style={{flex:1}}>

            <Text style={styles.titleText}>email</Text>
            <Form>
              <Input
                placeholder="example@gmail.com"
                placeholderColor="rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.55)"
                style={styles.inputStyle}
              />
            </Form>

            <Button style={styles.nextButton}>
              <Text>Next</Text>
            </Button>

          </Content>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginEmailContainer;
```

I tried to `null` the `behavior` of `KeyboardAvoidingView` but it did not work.
I also tried `keyboardVerticalOffset` to -500 but this did not work either.

https://snack.expo.io/rkXnqiXaV

Snack of my code.
It's not exactly like my app.
It works roughly alike.

Comment: in adjustResize and adjustPan, you have displayed them with first capital letter, check in your code and use it as : `adjustResize`

Answer (score 0):

React Native documentation says:

Android may behave better when given no behavior prop at all, whereas iOS is the opposite.

I believe for navigation you are using react-navigation library.
Keyboardavoidingview does not consider header height. So you need to give header height in offset value.

keyboardVerticalOffset = {Header.HEIGHT + 20}

Answer (score 0):

> "**adjustResize**"
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.
>
> "**adjustPan**"
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

your requirement will work like this:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

you need to add this in your activity tag and with `android:name=".MainActivity"`